# How can you nest an ASP.Net User Control inside of itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I think the short answer is you can't, but there has to be someway to make it happen. I want to make a list of items, that then have a list of items within them, nesting only one level. ie:

```
 Repeater  
    UserControl1  
        UserControl1  
        UserControl1  
    UserControl1
        UserControl1  
    UserControl1  
    UserControl1
```

I'd really like to avoid using LoadControl if at all possible since I'm adding to this list inside of server side Click events so I can't do loadControl on PageInit to get all the viewstate stuff to work.

I'm going to attempt to write out a quick psuedo code example, it looks like this:

**Page.aspx**

```
<asp:repeater runat="Server" id="someRepeater">
<uc:UserControl1 runat="Server" id="ctrlParent" />
</asp:repeater>
```

**UserControl1.ascx**

```
<asp:label id="label1" runat="server" />
<asp:repeater runat="server" id="childRepeater">
    <uc:UserControl1 runat="server" id="ctrlChild" />
</asp:repeater>
```

**UserControl1.ascx.vb**

```
If me.HasChildren then
    'BindChildRepeater'
end if

sub Fill(Data as RelevantData)
    label1.Text = Data.SomeText
end sub

sub ChildRepeater_ItemDataBound(object as sender, e as someArgs)
    Dim childCtrl = e.item.findcontrol("ctrlChild")
    childCtrl.Fill(e.item.dataitem)
end sub
```

Comment: You can have a _different instance_ nested.

Comment: It gives you a circular reference error if you put it within itself.  I've even attempted to place the user control inside a new UserControl... ie: UserControl1Child which is nothing more than a container UserControl for the parent item. And it also gives me a circular reference error.  Placed them in different directories as well.

Comment: Without seeing your code and knowing how the user control has been implemented, it is impossible to answer the question fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest a repeater inside a repeater

```
<asp:repeater runat="Server" id="someRepeater1">
    <uc:UserControl1 runat="Server" id="ctrlParent1" />
    <asp:repeater runat="Server" id="someRepeater2">
        <uc:UserControl1 runat="Server" id="ctrlParent2" />
    </asp:repeater>
</asp:repeater>
```

Comment: This works, it would be great if there was some way for the actual user control to be the parent to it's children items in the control hierarchy, and not have a list of child items after it in a repeater.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `<%@ Register src="" tagname="" tagprefix=""%>` in the user contol in which you want to call the another user control.. Calling an user control inside another user control is same like calling a user control in normal aspx page.

Comment: post the exact source, we cant build bricks without clay

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. Basically controls that you add using LoadControl will be gone after postback, so what I did is simply call this function during postback in `Page_Load`

```
Private Sub AddSubCategorizedQuestionItemControls()

    If rptSubCategorizedquestionList.Items IsNot Nothing AndAlso
        rptSubCategorizedquestionList.Items.Count > 0 Then

        For Each _item As RepeaterItem In rptSubCategorizedquestionList.Items

            If _item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem OrElse
                     _item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then

                Dim _hfCategoryID As HiddenField = _item.FindControl("hfCategoryID")

                Dim _placeHolderSubCategoryQuestionItem As PlaceHolder = _item.FindControl("placeHolderSubCategoryQuestionItem")

                Dim _nestedCategorizedListItemControlUserControlObject As UserControl =
                                                                LoadControl("__categorizedQuestionListItem.ascx")

                _nestedCategorizedListItemControlUserControlObject.ID =
                                      String.Format("ucCategorizedQuestionListItem", _hfCategoryID.Value)

                _placeHolderSubCategoryQuestionItem.Controls.Add(_nestedCategorizedListItemControlUserControlObject)

                Dim _nestedCategorizedListItem As Common_Questions__categorizedQuestionListItem =
                    DirectCast(_nestedCategorizedListItemControlUserControlObject, Common_Questions__categorizedQuestionListItem)

            End If

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```